# Having trouble with dates stored in database, dateformat, select distinct, and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a table containing a column (VARCHAR) with dates that are stored in this format: d.m.Y (i.e. 09.11.2019).

I need to read out distinct dates, limit 10, newest dates.

I tried this code, but it only sort by d, and not m or Y.

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM tbl ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert date strings to dates using [mysql date function `str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
select distinct date from tbl order by str_to_date(date, '%d.%m.%Y') desc limit 10
```

Format specifiers:

- `%d`: Day of the month, numeric (01..31)
- `%m`: Month, numeric (01..12)
- `%Y`: Year, numeric, four digits

NB: generally speaking, always use a date-like datatype (`date`, `datetime`) to represent dates in your database. Storing dates as strings *will* bite you in many ways.